# Frontpage for Application

Tags: front-matter

Minimal case

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}
\title{Investigation of the Neuronal Component of Purkinje Fibers with Suppressed Simple Spikes \\ Plan of the Research}
\author{MB SB Sami Lorem, Lorem Lorem Ipsun, Hello World, PhD Ipsun Lorem}
\begin{titlepage}
\maketitle
\end{titlepage}
\end{document}
```

which looks like

[image]

I do not like so much the big title, since subtitle and title are the same size. 
If there is any standard of some major university, please, mention it.

**How can you type better the titlepage of the research plan?** 
Is there any ready package for that. 
I think the subtitle should be smaller than the bigger title. 
However, I am not sure if **Plan of the Research** is the title and the long thing only subtitle, or vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is not clear for me what you are searching beside a `\small` command after "Spikes", but consider using another document class as `paper`:

[image: MWE]

```
\documentclass{paper}
\title{
Investigation of the Neuronal Component
of Purkinje Fibers with Suppressed Simple Spikes
}
\subtitle{Plan of the Research}
\author{
MB SB Sami Lorem, Lorem Lorem Ipsun,\and 
Hello World \& PhD Ipsun Lorem}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear answer! You are awesome!